# service authenticating against azure ad and EWS

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am building a daemon/non-interactive service to use EWS in O365 as a specific user. In order to communicate with EWS over OAUTH2.0 I am trying to properly register the application and authenticate against AAD. Preferably I would like to use certificate based authentication, but I did not get that far.

The code is below (its working):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string tenant = "redacted.onmicrosoft.com";
        string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant;
        string clientId = "44964df2-3333-2222-1111-redcated";
        string resource = "https://outlook.office365.com";
        string clientSecret = "redacted";
        string username = "username@redacted.onmicrosoft.com";
        string password = "redacted";

        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = null;
        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);

        var userCred = new UserPasswordCredential(username, password);
        ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

        string errorMessage = null;
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Trying to acquire token");
            authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, userCred).Result;
        }
        catch (AdalException ex)
        {
            errorMessage = ex.Message;
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                errorMessage += "\nInnerException : " + ex.InnerException.Message;
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            errorMessage = ex.Message;
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed: {0}" + errorMessage);
            return;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nMaking the protocol call\n");
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
        service.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authenticationResult.AccessToken);
        service.TraceEnabled = true;
        service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;
        service.Url = new Uri(resource + "/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
        EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(service);
        email.ToRecipients.Add("redacted@gmail.com");
        email.Subject = "HelloWorld from EWS";
        email.Body = new MessageBody("Test from EWS");
        email.Send();
    }
```

This code works as intended, however, I also need to ensure that it is secure/according to best practice.

When using the code, I registered the application as "Native", however, I have later found that Micrsofts manual says you should not use client_secret with Native applications, and the client secret is not actually used by the code either in its current form.

Considering the use case (non-interactive service authenticate as one specific user), is this the correct approach?

What should I consider when registering the service in AAD?

Answer (score -1):

> I have later found that Micrsofts manual says you should not use
>   client_secret with Native applications

[Client_secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code#use-the-authorization-code-to-request-an-access-token) cannot be used in a native app (public client), because client_secrets cannot be reliably stored on devices. It is required for web apps and web APIs (all confidential clients), which have the ability to store the client_secret securely on the server side.

> Considering the use case (non-interactive service authenticate as one
>   specific user), is this the correct approach?

Yes, the OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Grant Flow permits a web service (confidential client) to use its own credentials instead of impersonating a user, to authenticate when calling another web service. While Oauth 2.0 auth code grant flow and OpenId Connect is impersonating a user that needs the user sign in.

> What should I consider when registering the service in AAD?

You could read this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/about-microsoft-identity-platform), it will introduce the main structure about the AAD service.

Comment: This answer does not help at all. Client Credentials Grant Flow is out of the question due to its extensive need for access rights (i.e. give access to all users mailbokses rather than 1 single user). Auth Code grant flow is out of the question for a non-interactive service as it does not allow signin without a browser popup (with ADAL).

Regarding the doc: I have read through it several times. Microsofts manual does a poor job in mapping OAUTH2.0 to ADAL and AAD app registration. When are the different grant flows used in ADAL? What should be the correct app type in AAD for these?